# How to start a conda/mamba environment in a container during execution

Tags: containers, conda, singularity-container, mamba

I would like to do exec on my container and execute my command:

`apptainer exec myContainer.sif myCommand`

(or singularity)

but *myCommand* is within a conda/mamba environment, so I am doing:

`apptainer exec myContainer.sif bash -c 'source /opt/mamba/etc/profile.d/mamba.sh; source activate mambaEnvironment; myCommand'`

And this works fine. I tried to set  up  the mamba environment activation on the section of the definition file like so:

```
%environment
  PATH=$PATH:/bbmap/:/opt/mamba/bin/
  . /opt/mamba/etc/profile.d/mamba.sh
  mamba activate blee
```

but it doesn't seem to do anything.  I basically would like to set it up so that everytime I do apptainer exec (or singularity exec) it loads to appropriate mamba/conda environment (this so that I can run it easily as part of a nextflow pipeline). How can I do this?

Below is an example recipe:

```
Bootstrap: docker
From: ubuntu:20.04

%post
  apt-get -y update
  apt-get -y upgrade
  DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
  apt-get -y install default-jre
  apt-get -y --no-install-recommends install wget git zlib1g-dev curl openssh-client tar gzip ca-certificates build-essential cmake

  #Install Mamba
  readonly mamba_installer="Mambaforge-$(uname)-$(uname -m).sh"
  readonly mamba_version="4.10.3-4"
  readonly mamba_prefix="/opt/mamba"
  wget "https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge/releases/download/${mamba_version}/${mamba_installer}"
  bash "${mamba_installer}" -b -p "${mamba_prefix}"
  rm "${mamba_installer}"
  export PATH="/opt/mamba/bin:$PATH"

  PATH=$PATH:/bbmap/
  mamba config --add channels defaults
  mamba config --add channels conda-forge
  mamba config --add channels bioconda

  mamba create -y -n blee python=3.6 pip
  mamba init
  . /opt/mamba/etc/profile.d/mamba.sh
  . activate blee
  mamba install -n blee -c bioconda nanocomp porechop

%environment
  PATH=$PATH:/bbmap/:/opt/mamba/bin/
  . /opt/mamba/etc/profile.d/mamba.sh
  mamba activate blee

%runscript
    exec "$@"
```

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, conda/mamba environments are only activated on interactive logins, even if you put activation in the `.bashrc` file.

If you add the env bin to `PATH` it usually works, but can require more paths being added to scripts. Something like `ENV PATH /opt/mamba/env/blee/bin:$PATH`. Also remember to update shebang if you are using executable scripts.